# precompiled header files usage for library builders

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688053/what-to-put-in-precompiled-header-msvc/688091#688091) boost and STL headers belong into the **precompiled header file** (`stdafx.h` in the MSVC world). So I changed the headers of my dynamic link library project and moved all STL/Boost headers into the `stdafx.h` of my project.

**Before**

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

namespace XXX
{
  class CLASS_DECL_BK CExampleClass // CLASS_DECL_BK is just a standard dll import/export macro
  {
    private:
      boost::scoped_ptr<Replica> m_replica;
  }
}
```

**After**

```
namespace XXX
{
  class CLASS_DECL_BK CExampleClass
  {
    private:
      boost::scoped_ptr<Replica> m_replica;
  }
}
```

Now I have the advantage of decreased compile times, **but** all the users of my library are getting build errors (e.g. unknown boost::scoped_ptr...) because of the missing includes (which are now moved to my `stdafx.h`).

---

**What could be a solution for this dilemma?**

I want reduced compile times **and** compile errors after including my headers files are not acceptable for any users of the dll.

Could this help?

- leave all includes directives as they are but duplicate them in my 'stdafx.h'? Since the stdafx.h is always included first inside any cpp file of my project I should be fine, and the users won't get any errors. Or do I loose the speed advantage if multiple includes of the same header occur in one translation unit (got header guards)?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get *nearly* the same speed increase when you leave the header-includes in place in the library headers and just additionally put them into `stdafx.h`.

Alternatively, you could add an additional define (a bulk [external include guard](http://www.bobarcher.org/software/include/index.html))

```
// stdafx.h
#define MY_LIB_STD_HEADERS_ALREADY_INCLUDED

// library_file.h
#ifndef MY_LIB_STD_HEADERS_ALREADY_INCLUDED
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
...
#endif
```

But I would only do that if you are *sure* it helps. Just take a stopwatch and run a few re-compilations. (No need to link.) Then you'll see if there's any difference.

### Aside

I'm not sure if adding *all* boost headers that are needed *somewhere* in the project is such a good idea. I'd say `shared_ptr`and friends, `boost/foreach`, maybe Boost.Format, ... are a good idea, but I'd already think twice for the Boost.RegExp headers. <sub>Note: I [*did not* do any speed measurements](http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-care-and-feeding-of-pre-compiled-headers), but I dimly remember a problem with the size of the pch file and some compiler hiccup. I really [should do some tests](http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-care-and-feeding-of-pre-compiled-headers/comment-page-1#comment-178).</sub>

Also check if the Boost Library in question provides forwarding headers and whether you should include them instead. Bloating the precompiled header file can have it's downsides.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a build configuration for this purpose (Debug, Release, CheckDependencies). a simple way to change this would be to use the preprocessor to include/exclude the includes based on the current configuration. using this, you can test and build using debug or release (which contains the larger set of includes), then build all configurations before distribution.

to clarify, the conditional include `MON_LIBRARY_VALIDATE_DEPENDENCIES` is not to be used in the library headers or sources, only in the precompiled header:

```
// my pch:
#include <file1.hpp>
#include <file2.hpp>
// ...

#if !defined(MON_LIBRARY_VALIDATE_DEPENDENCIES)
#include <boost/stuff.hpp>
// ...
#endif
```

then you would append `MON_LIBRARY_VALIDATE_DEPENDENCIES` to the list of preprocessor definitions in the CheckDependencies configuration.

regarding guards: it *should* not be a problem if you are using guards under normal circumstances - compilers use optimizations to detect these cases which means they can avoid opening the file in many cases if it's been multiply included and guarded correctly. in fact, attempts to outsmart the compiler in this arena can actually slow *down* to process. i'd say just leave it as typical unless your library/dependencies are huge and you really have noticeable problems.

Comment: I guess your solution would fix the problem. A downside I see with it is, that preprocessing code (#ifdef and friends) will make the source harder to read/understand. I also could run into problems forcing my more lazy colleagues to add include directives for the different build configurations into their header files. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @nabulke sorry if that was not clear; the #ifdef is used only in the  precompiled header. will update...

Answer (score 1):

Making your compilation units selfcontained (let them include everything they use) is very desirable. This will prevent compilation errors from others that do not use precompiled headers, and as you assume, header guards will keep the cost of these extra includes minimal.

This will also have the desirable side effect that a glance at the headers will tell the users which other headers are in use in the unit, and the options of doing a compilation of the single unit without any fuzz.

Comment: So you think the duplication of includes described in my question would be ok and provide a speedup in compilation times?

Comment: Yes you will have your speedup and the other users of your units will have code that can be compile and read.